# How do we preserve the order of CSV data during CSV format convert to JSON format?

Tags: java, json, csv

I am writing a code that will read the data in CSV format and convert it to JSON format without disrupting the order. However, when you type jsonArray(jsonObjekt) the order changes. What should I do to maintain the order?

Comment: Why does the order matter, if the properties are _named_? Maybe you should parse to arrays rather than an object.

Comment: Sounds like you're treating json as text. That would be a no-no

Comment: It's for unit testing ?

Comment: How are you converting the CSV? Are you using any libraries? Let's see some code, please.

Comment: JSON objects are unordered pairs of keys and values. Some implementation may preserve an order, but implementations are not required to maintain it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. As your question is currently written, it is a little difficult to answer. Please _edit_ your question and include a [mcve] where you show how you parse the CSV and how you create the JSON data. Also, JSON objects are by their nature unordered. Therefore, if order is important to you, you should rather encode the data as a JSON array. But again, we need to see a sample of your data to give you meaningful advice. Cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

> I am writing a code that will read the data in CSV format and convert it to JSON format without disrupting the order.

Ok, that's not so hard, given a working CSV reader.  You haven't presented any code, but you haven't given me any particular reason to think you would have done it incorrectly.  Not even ...

> when you type jsonArray(jsonObjekt) the order changes.

. The order of entries in a Javascript object is unspecified, and the order in which they are expressed in a JSON serialization of such an object is not significant.  You can produce JSON in which the keys appear in the order you choose, but that does not require software that reads your JSON into an internal object representation to iterate the resulting object's keys in any particular order, or even in a consistent order.

If key order is significant for you then a JSON object is the wrong data structure, or at least not a sufficient one.  In JSON, the aggregate data structure that preserves order is the array, so that's where you should be looking.

You could use an array of single-entry objects, for example.  Or you could express the key order via a separate array of the keys alone, so that if you want to look up a value by index, you get the corresponding key from the array (by index), and use the key to retrieve the wanted value from the object.  Or one data structure that would map directly onto CSV would be an optional array of keys plus a separate array, one element per CSV record, with the elements being arrays of the records' data values.